# Advanced string replace with start to length

Tags: php

```
$string = 'Justin Timberlake (One Direction)';
$string = str_replace('????', '',$string);
```

I want everything within `()` to be removed, include the bracket, is it possible with `str_replace`? Sometime it could be like this `(    fff)`. regex is harder to maintain so I avoid that.

Comment: I would still use regex for this. Or split the string, replace, rejoin the strings.

Comment: Could possibly use a combination of `strpos` to find the opening `(`, then `strpos` again to find the closing `)` and join two `substr` from 0 to `(` and from `)` to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `str_replace` is feasible here, as it searches for a **specific** string to replace, and we cannot give it a **specific** string to replace, as `(One Direction)` can change. (I'm assuming it can change, and therefore not a viable option). Here's two alternatives;

#### Not using regular expressions

```
<?php

$string = "Justin Timberlake (One Direction)";
echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "("));
```

https://eval.in/194261

#### Using regular expressions

```
<?php

$string = "Justin Timberlake (One Direction)";
$string = preg_replace("/\(.*\)/", "", $string);
echo $string;
```

https://eval.in/194255

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_replace` like in this question: [Remove Text Between Parentheses PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174362/remove-text-between-parentheses-php)

```
$string = "ABC (Test1)";
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);
```

Edit:

```
$string = "ABC (Test1)";
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]*\)/","",$string);
```

Comment: This will fail. If the brackets are empty (ie: `()`), then the brackets won't be removed. "**include the bracket**". The `+` means match 1 or more of the preceding token. Change that to `*`

Comment: You're right, that works better in cases there's nothing between the ()

Comment: If I have `(One )Direction))`, it will only replace `(One )` with an empty string, leaving `Direction))`, which still fails OPs requirements. - doesn't it?

Comment: It does but in this case this is the answer for his question, you can always use str_replace again to delete all () which are still in the string

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change content inside ()

https://eval.in/194270

```
<?php

$string = "Justin Timberlake (One Direction)";
$start = '(';
$end = ')';
if (strpos($string,$end) !== false) {
            $startpos = strpos($string, $start) + strlen($start);
            if (strpos($string, $start) !== false) 
            {
            $endpos = strpos($string, $end, $startpos);
                if (strpos($string, $end, $startpos) !== false)
                {
                  $data_replace= substr($string, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos);
                }               
            }
   }
$data_insert = "Sing Song";
echo $data_updated = str_replace($data_replace,$data_insert,$string);   
?>
```