# Trying to remove empty braces in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, trim

I am having a string `MyText (text in braces)`. I am trying to remove spaces at beginning and ending. Also, I want to remove empty braces `()` like this. For example, if my string is like this `MyText ()`, I have to remove `()` and print `MyText`.

My PHP code:

```
$str = 'MyText (text in braces) ';
echo trim($str, ' ()');
```

My output is `MyText (text in braces` It is trimming the outer brace also. But it should not remove that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174362/remove-text-between-parentheses-php

Comment: Try [`preg_replace('~^\s+|(?:\s+|\(\)\s*)$~', '', $s);`](http://ideone.com/JTgWkp)

Comment: I think it should be `/^\s+|(?:\s+|\s+\(\)\s*)$/g` to trim spaces before empty parentheses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew preg_replace is overkill.  For such a simple match str_replace is more than adequate.

Comment: @GordonM: Unless the `()` must only be removed at the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<?php
    $str = 'MyText (text in braces) ';
    echo trim(str_replace("()", "", $str));
```