# How to Remove Text Between brackets with php

Tags: php

How to remove text Between brackets.
For exp.

```
$str = 'Aylmers(test, test2), Ancaster(Clandeboye, Bluevale)';

i want to get as
$str = 'Aylmers, Ancaster';
```

Comment: For nested brackets you can check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278345/how-to-remove-text-between-brackets-with-php/51278504#51278504

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$str = 'Aylmers(test, test2), Ancaster(Clandeboye, Bluevale)';
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$str );
```

output:

```
Aylmers, Ancaster
```

[Regex](https://regexone.com/)

Comment: unfortunately this does not remove nested brackets such as A (B (C) D) and leaves you with A D

Comment: For nested brackets we need to modify regix but I have created for current requirement.

Comment: FYI - Those are not brackets. They are *parentheses*.  Brackets look like this: [ ]

Comment: @billynoah, thanks, Parenthesis "()", curly brackets "{}", square brackets "[]"

Comment: ok, well then maybe that's a difference in dialect - in America anyway it's typically: Parentheses (), Brackets [], Braces {}

Answer (score 0):

### This should do it:

```
`<?php`
`$string = "Stay 01 (Remove 01), Stay 02 (Remove 02)";`
`echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string); // 'ABC '`
```

Answer (score 0):

If also want to remove *nested* data in brackets. You can use:

```
$str = 'Aylmers(test, test2), Ancaster(Clandeboye, Bluevale)';
echo preg_replace("/\(([^()]*+|(?R))*\)/","", $str);

//output:
//Aylmers, Ancaster
```

Explanation:

> /  - Opening delimiter
>
> ( - Match opening parenthesis
>
> [^)]+ - Match character that is not a closing parenthesis
>
> ) - Match closing parenthesis
>
> /  - Closing delimiter

Comment: It's nice that you added some explanation, but if you're going to explain, then explain why/how it matches nested parenthesis, rather than just a single pair. Having such an explanation would make this actually better than the [effectively identical code in an answer on the dup-target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31788152/3773011).